# How to pass styled components transient props to nested component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I created such a component:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button<{ $variant: string }>`
  ...
`
```

`$variant` props is a transient prop (I don't want to pass it to DOM element (button) and it works. What if I want to nest this component like below?

```
const SpecialButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  ...
`
```

unfortunate, `$variant` is not passed down to StyledButton.

Is it possible to pass the transient prop down until it goes to the DOM element?

Comment: By definition, transient props are not rendered onto DOM elements. If you require it to be rendered onto the DOM element, then you need to remove the $ from the property name.

Comment: @Benjamin `StyledButton` is not a DOM element, but I can't pass props down to it

Answer (score 3):

In this example you could see transient prop is indeed available in `Comp2`.
Hope this solves your query ;)

[image]

Also you can see the transient prop is not visible in DOM
[image]

Comment: The problem in this example is that $variant is not passed to Comp1

Comment: There is no `Comp1` in the code :)

Comment: Like @wwilkowski was trying to say, in your example `$variant` is not passed to `Comp`, because styled-components consumes it in `Comp2` and doesn't pass it down. The original question is whether it is possible to pass the transient prop through `Comp2` to `Comp` while keeping the `$` preface

Answer (score 0):

I am probably too late with this but given your example:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button<{ $variant: string }>`
  ...
`
```

you would use your `<StyledButton />` component like so:

```
<StyledButton $variant="YOUR_BUTTON_VARIANT" />
```

now if you forked the `<StyledButton />` as you mentioned:

```
const SpecialButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  ...
`
```

you would still be able to access all of the props from the parent component as they are inherited by the fork.

```
<SpecialButton $variant="YOUR_BUTTON_VARIANT" />
```

In the `<SpecialButton />` you can then just consume the props like so:

```
const SpecialButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.$variant === 'YOUR_BUTTON_VARIANT' ? 'blue' : 'yellow'};
`
```

or you could destructure the props object like so:

```
const SpecialButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  background-color: ${({ $variant }) => $variant === 'YOUR_BUTTON_VARIANT' ? 'blue' : 'yellow'};
`
```

You could even add props to the forked component:

```
const SpecialButton = styled(StyledButton)<{ $additionalProp: boolean }>`
  background-color: ${({ $variant }) => $variant === 'YOUR_BUTTON_VARIANT' ? 'blue' : 'yellow'};
  color: ${({ $additionalProp }) => $additionalProp ? 'black' : 'orange'};
`
```

One thing to note here is that you can add additional props to the fork but then you can't use those on the parent component because it only works in one direction. Meaning, you can only extend the parent but not make parent inherit props from it's offspring. In some scenarios you might just want to make some props on the parent component optional.

I hope this answers your question.